# using hibernate to generate one to many relation through annotation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I am just a beginner in learning Spring MVC and Hibernate technologies. 
I am trying to use hibernate to access my database and I am using annotation method to configuring my beans to database. I am trying to make a one to many relation which is throwing me error.

Basically I am it is a "one use can post multiple quiz" relation

the error while configuring hibernate is :
**org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.User.quizPosted[bean.Quiz]
Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: bean.User.quizPosted[bean.Quiz]**

my code for the two beans are :

User.java

```
    package bean;

    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="User", uniqueConstraints ={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="userName"})})
    public class User {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Person.class)
        @JoinColumn(name="PersonId")
        private Person person;

        @Column(name="userName")
        private String userName;

        @Column(name="password")
        private String password;

        @Column(name="role")
        private String role;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "postedBy")
        private Set<Quiz> quizPosted = new HashSet<Quiz>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userId")
        private Set<User_Quiz> user_Quizs = new HashSet<User_Quiz>();
    }
```

and quiz.java

```
    package bean;

    import java.sql.Date;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;


    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Quiz")
    public class Quiz {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer quizId;

        @Column(name = "duration")
        private Integer duration;

        @Column(name = "date")
        private Date date;

        @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
        @JoinColumn(name = "postedBy")
        private User postedBy;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="quizId")
        private Set<User_Quiz> user_Quizs = new HashSet<User_Quiz>();        

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have unmaped classes in your Defined annotated class which means that all the classes which you have used in OnetoMany and ManyToOne relationships must be defined in Application Context as you have defined that you are using spring. In ur session factory add ur class in annotatedClasses property.

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
   <property name="annotatedClasses">
     <list>
       <value>test.package.Foo</value>
       <value>test.package.Bar</value>
     </list>
   </property>
 </bean>
```

See [Annotated Session Factory](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html)